# Photograph used without my consent

Tags: copyright, photography

I became internet bestfriends with someone and she took not just mine but some of my bestfriends photos that we posted on social media and she used them but creepily she printed our photos out and she also posted pictures of me on all of her social media accounts. Would it be illegal to use our photos without us knowing?

Answer (score 1):

### it’s almost certainly legal

The licence you grant when you post on social media is usually incredibly broad (different companies have different licences so I’m speaking generally). They usually allow anyone to use them for anything they want.

For example, here on [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) you agree to an irrevokable [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) licence which allows Stack Exchange to share it and adapt it providing that they attribute you and allow everyone else to do the same.

Comment: @DaleM, actually, it's quite possibly illegal.  My experience is that those incredibly broad copyright licenses make generous use of the word "exclusive", so that a photo uploaded to one social-media site can't legally be uploaded to another.

Comment: @Mark That's my understanding, as well. I always thought the platforms' TOS's required users to give *them* license to copy photos, not to license them to the entire world.

Comment: @Mark I believe most sites have you agree to the attribution of a [Creative Commons license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) just like Stack does when uploading. That essentially means, you post it.. anyone can use it as long as they aren't directly profiting from its use.

Comment: If you post your personal photos on social media site A and someone reposts them on social media site B, what would your damages be?

Comment: @DaviddSchwartz maybe Libel?